# Javascript enter keypress isn't recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Inside Bootstrap modal windows I have this piece of html:

```
   <form class="form-inline" role="form">
      <button  type="button" class="btn btn-training-comment btn-lg">
        <a href="#"> <img src="/img/training-icon-large.png" alt="icon" width="35" height="24"></a>
      </button>

     <div class="form-group training-comment-form-wrapper">
         <label class="sr-only" for="commentInput">Enter comment..</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control training-comment" id="commentInput" placeholder="Enter comment">
      </div>
    </form>
```

And I have this Javascript code:

```
$("#commentInput").onkeypress = function (e) {
    if (!e) e = window.event;
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode == '13') {
        console.log("clicked");
        addComment();
    }
};
```

But my enter key press isn't captured and  "clicked" never gets logged. Why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your onkeypress to use .on() and removed some other unnecessary things. You were also comparing a number to a string. keyCode == '13' . Hope this helps.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('keypress','#commentInput', function (e) {
        console.log('Keyboard Key Number: '+e.which);
        if (e.which == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('enter was pressed. ');
        }
    });
});
```

Also, you should remove the anchor tag nested within the . There is no need for that.

```
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-training-comment btn-lg">
    <a href="#"> <img src="/img/training-icon-large.png" alt="icon" width="35" height="24"></a>
  </button>
```

Here is a working fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/FVK7f/ - (Using your markup) with an additional wrapping div around the form.

Edit: changed event binding to use document.

Comment: Thanks but still nothing :(

Comment: Where do you have jquery included?

Comment: It's not problem with jQuery, I've included it on page which calls modal and when this didn't work I've included it in modal template just to be sure

Comment: hmm.. made and edit to use "$(document).on('keypress','#commentInput'," , try that. The event may not be binding because that markup is being injected in to the page. 

Also, you shouldn't have a <a> tag inside a button. 

http://jsfiddle.net/FVK7f/

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$("#commentInput").keypress(function (e) {
```

instead

```
$("#commentInput").onkeypress = function (e) {
```

The quotes in

```
if (keyCode == '13') {
```

are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for answer but it din't help